# Distortion On Microphone (X79-UP4)

Tags: windows-8, microphone, distortion

My motherboard X79-UP4 Running Windows 8 Enterprise, Has a weird problem when trying to use the microphone port.

Not really sure how to describe the sound so have attached a link below.

Here is a sample of the audio. [Sound Sample](http://www39.zippyshare.com/v/47249468/file.html)

So Far I Have:

Update the bios.
Reinstalled the drivers.
Updated the drivers.
Tried Multiple Microphones.
Tried Line In

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lots of investigation. It seems Windows 8 is to blame. I have tested on Windows 7 with no problems.

Problem is resolved